# "The specified value is out of range" exception during call to ReadValueAsync()

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'd like to read BLE GATT characteristic using following code:

```
GattReadResult result = await idCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

Unfortunately I get "The specified value is out of range" System.ArgumentException (HRESULT -2147024809). ReadValueAsync() is called just after connection. If I add 1 second delay with Thread.Sleep() there is no exception and the characteristic is read without any problem. I get the exception on Windows 10.0.16278, on 10.0.14393 there is no issue. The exception suggests BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached is the source of problem. But it is valid mode and I haven't found any information that it is disallowed in any situation.

Comment: There unfortunately seems to be many bugs in Windows's BLE implementation in the latest updates. Just look at the msdn forum. I can't understand why they release stuff that seems completely untested and break previously working apps.